# Get exit code of SFTP command run by system()

Tags: c++, system, expect

my program created a script that executes sftp command using expect. The script should download a file from SFTP server. When the script is generated, my program call system command to run the script. The script should exit when an error is encountered. For example, if the password is wrong. How am I be able to get the error returned by sftp command?

Below is the code that generates and run the script:

```
downloadFileFromServer()
{
    ofstream downloadScript;
    string  result, command;

    downloadScript.open("/temp/download.sh");

    downloadScript << "#!/usr/bin/expect -f \n";
    downloadScript << "spawn sftp -P " + <port number> +
                      " " + <user name> +
                      "@" + <IP> + "\n";
    downloadScript << "expect { \ntimeout {\nsend_user \"Permission denied\\n\"\nexit\n}\n}\n";

    downloadScript << "send \"" + <password> + "\\n\"\n";
    downloadScript << "expect \"sftp>\"""\n";
    downloadScript << "send \"cd " + <source directory> + "\\n\"\n";
    downloadScript << "expect \"sftp>\"""\n";
    downloadScript << "send \"lcd " + <destination directory> + "\\n\"\n";
    downloadScript << "expect \"sftp>\"""\n";
    downloadScript << "send \"get " + <file name> + "\\n\"\n";
    downloadScript << "expect \"sftp>\"""\n";
    downloadScript << "send \"exit\\n\"\n";
    downloadScript << "expect -exact \"$\"""\n";

    downloadScript.close();

    command = "chmod +x /temp/download.sh && /temp/download.sh";
    system(command.c_str());

}
```

Below is the script created:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f 
spawn sftp -P <port numner> <user name>@<IP>
expect "<user name>@<IP>'s password:"
expect { 
timeout {
send_user "Permission denied\n"
exit
}
}
send "<password>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd <source directory>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "lcd <destination directory>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get <file name>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
expect -exact "$"
```

I want my program to catch the "Permission denied" error.

Comment: What language is your script-generation code written in?

Comment: see the manual of [system(3)](https://man.cx/system(3)) to see how to get the exit code.

Comment: Can you just set up SSH keys between your machine and the sftp server? That would make your life a lot simpler.

Comment: @ColinMacleod, I'm using C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All processes set a numeric exit code (0..255) when they end. Change the expect script so that you can distinguish between the script ending normally (when usually the exit code will be 0) and the explicit `exit` after an error. Do this by adding a parameter to that line, eg:

```
...
send_user "Permission denied\n"
exit 77
...
```

You can recover this code in a C/C++ program with

```
int wstatus = system(command.c_str());
if (WIFEXITED(wstatus))
  int exit_code = WEXITSTATUS(wstatus);
```

The `wstatus` is formed of 2 parts, the exit code of the process, and a some flags giving information about whether the process ran or was interrupted and so on. Use the above macros to extract the information.
See `man 3 exit`, `man waitpid`.

Comment: I tried to put exit 1 after "Permission denied" message. When I get the exit code returned by system(), the value is 256 instead of 1. Why is that?

Comment: I read from other article that in order to get the exit code, the returned value must be divided by 256. So if I put exit 77, the returned value would be 19712 (divided by 256 to get the value of 77).

Comment: You are right. `system()` returns an integer holding the exit code and other info. You should use the macros I added to my answer to extract the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the password before checking for timeouts

```
expect "<user name>@<IP>'s password:"
send "<password>\n"
expect {
    timeout {
        send_user "Permission denied\n"
        exit 1
    }
    "sftp>"
}
send "cd ..."
```

I have expect looking for either the timeout or the prompt, whichever one comes first.

Comment: Get the expect code correct before you try embedding it. Run it with `expect -d` to see why the pattern is not matching.

Comment: I read from other article that in order to get the exit code, the returned value must be divided by 256. So if I put exit 77, the returned value would be 19712 (divided by 256 to get the value of 77).

Comment: by the way, what is the correct way to put an error message or exit loop for cd command? I tried this but  it did not exit:

    expect { 
    send_user "No such file or directory\n"
    exit 2
    "sftp>" }

Comment: You should not have "send_user" in that spot: `send "cd ...\r"` then `expect { "No such file or directory" {exit 2} "sftp>" }` -- add newlines as appropriate